# RemoteIPInternalProxy / RemoteIPTrustedProxy

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, httpd.conf

I guess I'm stupid or what but I don't get this:

I'm using the  `RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For` within a VirtualHost configuration in order to determine GEO location of our users within our PHP application.

But I also would like to log the Remote IP of the clients within the apache logs.

The Apache combined log format looks like this:

```
LogFormat "%h (%{X-Forwarded-For}i) %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

According to documentation:

```
RemoteIPTrustedProxy Directive
```

> The RemoteIPTrustedProxy directive adds one or more addresses (or
>   address blocks) to trust as presenting a valid RemoteIPHeader value of
>   the useragent IP. Unlike the RemoteIPInternalProxy directive, any
>   intranet or private IP address reported by such proxies, including the
>   10/8, 172.16/12, 192.168/16, 169.254/16 and 127/8 blocks (or outside
>   of the IPv6 public 2000::/3 block) are not trusted as the useragent
>   IP, and are left in the RemoteIPHeader header's value.

In my case the directive looks like this:

```
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 172.31.0.0/16
```

Where I'm saying trust any PROXY forwarding from this local subnet.

BUT, when I set this Apache stops logging the remote IP because the forwarding proxy is valid now ?

So If I set:

```
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 10.10.10.10
```

The IP above doesn't exist. So the proxy servers from `172.31.0.0/16` are invalid now and therefore apache starts logging the remote IP header again?

Please, try to give me some guidance here, as obviously I don't understand this.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Restore %a to that format if you're going to use mod_remoteip.

In bugzilla, mod_remoteip fills in %a while it
removes from %{X-Forwarded-For}i.  So in a simple case with one
trusted proxy, %a will hold the value used to see in
X-Forwarded-For because of mod_remoteip